# Low cost options for displaying location maps

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps

EE2.8.1

We have a charity run website that currently uses the 'Google Maps for ExpressionEngine' module on some pages and the Javascript gmaps API on some other pages for displaying location maps.

The site makes around 100,000 calls per month to google maps, the problem is, being a charity, the cost (around £100 pm) has become too high for this approach to continue.

The locations that need mapping are limited to a county.

I've looked into other solutions:
Reinos gmaps (which was previously used and is installed, but was discarded by the previous dev) has several options for location maps; Openstreetmap, mapquest, TomTom, bing_maps, plus caching.

Will changing back to this module and setting up caching reduce their mapping costs? What option within this plugin would be better for us?

Or is there a better option to using this plugin, can I utilise caching to reduce calls?

Comment: As far as I know there are no fees for using Openstreepmap so that should be a no brainer.

Comment: Thank you, I was incorrectly told that there are no free services hosting openstreetmaps